# How does the clear_bit function in the Linux kernel work?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, inline-assembly

clear_bit is defined here, at http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.4/source/arch/alpha/include/asm/bitops.h#L60 as

```
static inline void
clear_bit(unsigned long nr, volatile void * addr)
{
    unsigned long temp;
    int *m = ((int *) addr) + (nr >> 5);

    __asm__ __volatile__(
    "1: ldl_l %0,%3\n"
    "   bic %0,%2,%0\n"
    "   stl_c %0,%1\n"
    "   beq %0,2f\n"
    ".subsection 2\n"
    "2: br 1b\n"
    ".previous"
    :"=&r" (temp), "=m" (*m)
    :"Ir" (1UL << (nr & 31)), "m" (*m));
}
```

This is clearly using some AT&T assembly syntax. ldl loads a long. bic clears a bit. stl_c stores the long. beq is a branch.

But what is going on after "2:"? What is "br?" What is

```
:"=%r" (temp), "=m" (*m)
:"Ir" (1UL << (nr & 31)), "m" (*m));
```

?

Comment: This code isn't for Intel x86 CPUs, it's for DEC Alpha CPUs.

Comment: See also [Load-link/store-conditional at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) and the [gcc manual about inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html). Basically it loads the value, does the operation then tries to write it back which may fail if the location has been changed in which case the whole thing is restarted. `br` is the branch back to the start. If you don't know the instructions consult a reference.

Comment: *clear_bit()* is atomic, while *__clear_bit()* isn’t. Compare their sources.